# Dealing with NULL in ObservableList Extractors

Tags: java, javafx, observable, extractor

I have an `ObservableList` with an extractor, so that the listener attached to the object fires when properties of the items in the list are changed:

```
ObservableList<User> users = FXCollections.observableArrayList(param -> new Observable[] {param.getDepartment().departmentNameProperty()});
```

However, if a user does not have a department (that is, `param.getDepartment()` is `null`), an NPE is thrown. This makes sense, since you can't get the `departmentNameProperty` (a `SimpleStringProperty`) from `null`.

Changing the `ObservableList` to:

```
ObservableList<User> users = FXCollections.observableArrrayList(param -> {
    if (param.departmentProperty() == null) {
        return new Observable[0];
    } else {
        return new Observable[]{param.getDepartment().departmentNameProperty();
    }
```

Fixes the NPE, but then the observable doesn't seem to fire correctly for changes to all positions in the list.

Is there a good way to deal with this? I'm currently working around it by not allowing a null department (the constructor now just creates a department with a name of ""), but that seems like a sloppy solution.

Comment: Can you post the `User` class and `Department` (I assume) class?

Comment: I’m a little confused.  Is the property null, or is the property’s value null?  I’m pretty sure a property should never be null.

Comment: OK: You have a department, which has a name-property. But how do you want to make a list of Users out of this name-property? Definitely not by wrapping the name-property inside some observable list and extractor stuff. Please offer a minimalistic example and a detailed description what you are trying to do.